# cross_origin error for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extension development and stuck at one point. Please help me.

Purpose of extension: This extension simple wants google login.

Work done so far:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/creative.css" type="text/css">
<title>TrustWall Authentication</title>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="header-content-inner">
                <div id="title">
                    <h1 id="s">TrustWall Demo</h1>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <p>This is a demo Plugin demostrating Trustwall touchID based
                    login</p>
                <div id="google_login">
                    <input id="google" type="button" value="Login by google"
                        class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll" />
                </div>
                <div id="sclconnect_login">
                    <input id="sclconnect" type="button" value="Login using TrustWall"
                        class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
<div id="profile"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Getting started example",
    "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://www.googleapis.com",
    "http://*.google.com/"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

index.js

```
function init(){
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
       po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onLoadCallback';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
}

function logout()
{
    gapi.auth.signOut();
    location.reload();
}
function login() 
{
  var myParams = {
    'clientid' : '775263086375-33h1eij26jocplkkv52h08jlfifohvkp.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin',
    'callback' : 'loginCallback',
    'approvalprompt':'force',
    'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
  };
  gapi.auth.signIn(myParams);
}

function loginCallback(result)
{
    if(result['status']['signed_in'])
    {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get(
        {
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        request.execute(function (resp)
        {
            var email = '';
            if(resp['emails'])
            {
                for(i = 0; i < resp['emails'].length; i++)
                {
                    if(resp['emails'][i]['type'] == 'account')
                    {
                        email = resp['emails'][i]['value'];
                    }
                }
            }
            var str = "Name:" + resp['displayName'] + "<br>";
            str += "Image:" + resp['image']['url'] + "<br>";
            str += "<img src='" + resp['image']['url'] + "' /><br>";
            str += "URL:" + resp['url'] + "<br>";
            str += "Email:" + email + "<br>";
            document.getElementById("profile").innerHTML = str;
            var e = document.getElementById("google_login");
                e.style.display = "none";
            var e1 = document.getElementById("sclconnect_login");
                e1.style.display = "block";
        }); 
    } 
}
function onLoadCallback()
{
    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyA4o1P6gHvaX1aem0lLNvKgVCSrxtge0pg');
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1',function(){});
    document.getElementById("google").onclick = login;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   init();
   var sclConnectBtn = document.getElementById("sclconnect_login");
    sclConnectBtn.style.display='none';
});
```

This plugin gives me Origin_mismatch error.
This might be because of improper javascript origin which needs to be mentioned in console. But dont know what to write there in javascript origin. My manifest.json has requested the permission for google.

Comment: You can use Chrome Identity API instead: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity There's also an another similar issue regarding this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830139/implementing-google-one-time-code-flow-authentication-from-chrome-extension

Comment: For answer please go to stackoverflow link which is mentioned in above code